# Getting an empty response from HERE GEO API using fetch i Node.js

Tags: node.js, geolocation, node-fetch

I am trying to send a request to 'HERE' Geo API from a node.JS code and getting an empty response
This is what i am doing:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const keepAliveAgent = new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});

var lat = '43.293162'
var long = '-85.920004'
var endpoint = 'https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=' + lat + '%2C' + long + '&apiKey={API_key}'
console.log(endpoint)
here = async function (endpoint) {
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();

    let response = await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'GET',
        agent: keepAliveAgent

    });
    console.log(response)
    var time = { 'Here Response': + (new Date().getTime() - start_time) + 'ms' };
    console.log(time)
    return [response.json(), time];

}
```

The response is:

```
[
    {},
    {
        "Here Response": "781ms"
    }
]
```

When i am using the same URL with a GET request in postman i am getting the right response
[image]
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try putting `,` instead of `%2C`?

Comment: Could you please tell which Here Geo API are you using? A URL would be better.

Comment: I tried using ',' instead of %2C i still got an empty response

Comment: The URL i am using is https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=43.293162%2C-85.920004&apiKey={APIKEY}

Comment: @OferB I'm asking about the API name. Could you tell me the API name or provide me the URL of the API documentation?

Comment: Also, posting a screenshot of your postman window with the correct response and all headers visible would be of great help in identifying the issue.

Comment: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-reverse-geocode-brief.html

Comment: I also added a screenshot of the correct response

Answer (score 1):

I used this code and it worked
Thanks

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const keepAliveAgent = new https.Agent({
    keepAlive: true
});

var lat = '43.293162'
var long = '-85.920004'
var endpoint = 'https://revgeocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/revgeocode?at=' + lat + '%2C' + long + '&apiKey={API_key}'
console.log(endpoint)
here = async function (endpoint) {
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();

       let response = await fetch(endpoint, {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow',
      agent: keepAliveAgent ,
      
    })
  let data = await response.json()
  console.log(data) 
  var time = { 'Here Response': + (new Date().getTime() - start_time) + 'ms' };
  console.log(time)
  return [data];

}
```